# how to read data from Firebase and populated it in autocomplectetextView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, autocompletetextview

how to read data(latitude and logitude) from firebase and populated it in autocomplectetextView
how can i access to this data data.features.properties.adress like the image below

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMwk6.png)

this is part of my json file

```
 "features": [
      {
         "type": "Feature",
         "properties": {
            "x": 17.254,
            "y": 20.424,
            "adress": "123 rue test"
         },
         "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
               [
                  [
                     17.73,
                     2.81,
                     1.88
                  ],
                  [
                     17.906,
                     20.661,
                     1.88
                  ],
                  [
                     17.95,
                     20.27,
                     1.88
                  ],
                  [
                     17.01,
                     20.1832277507,
                     1.88
                  ],
                  [
                     17.73,
                     20.81,
                     1.88
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      }]
```

I've tried this this code but it give me nothing and i don't know what is the problem

```
featRef.child("features/properties/adress");

    featRef.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot adress : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.i("adress", adress.getValue().toString()+"///////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                autoComplete.add(adress.getValue().toString());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MapsActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, autoComplete);
            autoTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the problem? You'll definitely want to handle the `firebaseError` in `onCancelled`, e.g. by `throw firebaseError.toException()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/22652/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-android#t=201610130452373175836

Comment: the problem is that i can get any data this code give me nothing

Comment: That *either* means the listener is getting cancelled (see my first comment on how to detect that) *or* that the client is not connected to the database.

Comment: yes i've tried that and discovered that the rules wasn't enabled and fixed it {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true
  }
}but i still geting no data

Comment: Is your `onDataChange()` method being invoked? Did you put a breakpoint in it? Keep in mind that we have no idea what's under `adress`, you might want to include that JSON (as text, no screenshot please) in your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i've added my json